# Sum of values in the map for specific key

Tags: java, hashmap, refactoring, java-8, java-stream

I have text file with a file that on every line contain pair of name and amount like this:

```
Mike 5
Kate 2
Mike 3
```

I need to sum these values by key. I resolved this in this way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    try {
        Files.lines(Paths.get("/Users/walter/Desktop/stuff.txt"))
                .map(line -> line.split("\\s+")).forEach(line -> {
                    String key = line[0];
                    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                        Integer oldValue = map.get(key);
                        map.put(key, oldValue + Integer.parseInt(line[1]));
                    } else {
                        map.put(line[0], Integer.parseInt(line[1]));
                    }
                });
        map.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + " " +v));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ;

}
```

How actually I could improve this code in more functional way, with abillity to process data more concurrently (using parallel streams, etc.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want to write functional code, the rule is: don't use `forEach`. This is an imperative solution and breaks functional code.

What you want is to split each line and group by the first part (key) while summing the second part (values):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = 
    Files.lines(Paths.get("/Users/walter/Desktop/stuff.txt"))
         .map(s -> s.split("\\s+"))
         .collect(groupingBy(a -> a[0], summingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1]))));
```

In this code, we are splitting each line. Then, we are grouping the Stream using [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) where:

- `classifier`, which is a function that classifies each item to extract the key of the resulting `Map`, just returns the first part of the line
- `downstream` is a collector that reduces each value having the same key: in this case, it is [`Collectors.summingInt(mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) which sums each integer extracted by the given mapper.

---

As a side-note (and just so you know), you could rewrite your whole `forEach` more simply using the new [`Map.merge(key, value, remappingFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method, with just a call to:

```
map.merge(line[0], Integer.valueOf(line[1]), Integer::sum);
```

This will put a new value with the key `line[0]` with the value `Integer.valueOf(line[1])` if this key did not exist, otherwise, it will update the key with the given remapping function (which is the sum of the old and new value in this case).

Comment: nice explanation ! And what about concurrent treatment in the example (paralell streams usage ) ?

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi I'm not sure reading lines in a file will parallelize well, but it's just a matter of calling `parallel()` on the Stream pipeline. Maybe it would be better to collect all the lines in a List and call `parallelStream()` on that List to group it by the first part of the line.